# How to retrieve images from Instagram API?

Tags: python, instagram, latitude-longitude, instagram-api

I want to crawl images from using Instagram API within any location

Here my code in python:

```
  from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
    client_id = ********
    client_secret = ******* 
    access_token = *******
    client_ip = *******

    q=None
    count=100
    lat=51.51608899635712
    lng=0.09891956707558282
    min_timestamp = '2015-12-07 22:00:00'
    max_timestamp = '2015-12-08 22:00:00'
    distance=1000


    api = InstagramAPI(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, client_ips= client_ip,access_token= access_token)

    media_all_ids = []
  media_id = api.media_search(q,count=20) + api.media_search(lat=lat, lng=lng, min_timestamp=min_timestamp, max_timestamp=max_timestamp, distance=distance)

    temp,max_tag = next.split('max_tag_id=')
    max_tag=str(max_tag)

    for media_id in media_ids:
        media_all_ids.append(media_id.id)

    counter = 1

    while next and counter <3 :
        more_media, next = api.media_search(lat, lng, min_timestamp, max_timestamp, distance, max_tag_id=max_tag)
        temp,max_tag=next.split('max_tag_id=')
        max_tag = str(max_tag)
        for media_id2 in more_media:
             media_all_ids.append(media_id2.id)
        print (len(media_all_ids))
        counter+=1

    media_all_ids=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(media_all_ids))
    print (len(media_all_ids))
```

The main problem is, it gives me the same error which i have no clue to solve:

```
  content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
in _do_api_request
    raise InstagramAPIError(status_code, content_obj['meta']['error_type'], content_obj['meta']['error_message'])
instagram.bind.InstagramAPIError: (400) APIInvalidParametersError-missing lat and lng
```

i want to print out their ID alongside their image link and the time the photo was captured. I was wondering if someone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Check what api.media_search is returning. The error says it's returning more than 2 values and it doesn't know how to unpack the rest of them.

Comment: Still gives me an error, even if i put the correct parameters

Comment: What do you mean by "putting the correct parameters"? `api.media_search` returns more that two values. Try this in a python console `a, b = (1, 2, 3)`. It will give you the same error. Rewriting it to `a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)` will fix the error.

Comment: media_ids,next,a,b,c,d,e = api.media_search(q,count,lat,lng,min_timestamp,max_timestamp,distance)

Comment: Still gives me the same error

Comment: Not that this solves your problem but do not shadow the [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) function.

Comment: Even if i replace it , still gives me an error :(, but i do need it because for instagram , the next function skips a page and collects all the details of that user with their posted image

Comment: I highly doubt you need to shadow the builtin to get it to work. The repo has some examples that assign to `next` but they also have examples that assign to `next_`. Please do the latter.

Comment: @nikihub OP is unpacking the result of the API call correctly. It [returns a 2-tuple](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/dfeebe91cf389017e1786bd153d3d1285406ee9e/instagram/bind.py#L161).

Answer (score 1):

The order of arguments matters. If you look [at the source](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/dfeebe91cf389017e1786bd153d3d1285406ee9e/instagram/client.py#L38), you'll see that you need to pass the arguments in the following order:

```
["q", "count"] + ['lat', 'lng', 'min_timestamp', 'max_timestamp', 'distance']
```

Try passing your arguments using their names to avoid this problem. You already do this for `max_tag_id=max_tag`, so do it for the rest.

I am not sure about `access_token`, though. It does not seem to be a parameter to the method. You are more familiar with the API client than I am, so I leave that to you.

Comment: raise InstagramAPIError(status_code, content_obj['meta']['error_type'], content_obj['meta']['error_message'])
instagram.bind.InstagramAPIError: (400) APIInvalidParametersError-missing lat and lng

Comment: How are you invoking `media_search` now?

Comment: @Mr_Shoryuken You did not do as my answer suggests. Try `media_search(lat=lat, lng=lng, )` et cetera.

Comment: @Mr_Shoryuken That means that the method is returning a tuple with more values than the number of variables you're unpacking to. This goes against what I found in the source code but you can figure out what you need to do by not unpacking and then printing the response. Like `response = api.media_search(...); print(response)`. This will show you how many values are in the tuple and you can unpack accordingly.

Comment: Btw I looked at the turple you presented in your awnser and realised the mistake i made , was wondering how would i structure it, i have updated the code above

Comment: @Mr_Shoryuken You *still* have not fixed your code in the way I asked you, and the error in your question doesn't apply to your code either.

Comment: So you want me to set each of those variables to itself for example lat = latitude ect?

Comment: @Mr_Shoryuken Yes. Refer to the arguments by name to avoid issues with ordering.